# Movie streaming with mplayer

Tags: linux, streaming, mplayer

How can I see a movie from one of several streaming sites?
I would like use mplayer, given a certain url.

For instance:

```
mplayer -url http://address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have the same problem, and I solved the problem in this way:

- open link in Chrome;
- press F12 to open console and go to the Network tab;
- before pressing "Play" clear history console, then press "Play";
- you will see some element in Network list, so order by "Type" and search for an alement of "application/octet-stream" type: right-click on this element and select "Copy as cURL": the bulk of the work has been done!
- close Chrome and open a console:
- paste cURL and put the stream in a new file, like in this way:

  curl ..... > movie
- now, in another tab, you can view your movie with mplayer, simply in this way:

  mplayer -fs movie -idx

**Explanation:**

-**fs** put your video in fullscreen
-**idx** *"Rebuilds index of files if no index was found, allowing seeking. Useful with broken/incomplete downloads, or badly created files."*